# How do i use DateTime in echo when i have $row-> for displaying results from database

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay, i am having an issue what i need to fix but i do not know how.

I want to display the date from my database in right order in showing the results.

---

**This is the code so far i have:**

```
1 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM famnews ORDER BY datum DESC"))
2                         {
3 // display records if there are records to display
4      if ($result->num_rows > 0)
5      { ;                                                                        
6      while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
7      $date = new DateTime('datum');
8        {                                                  
9          echo "<blockquote><strong>Datum:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row->$date->format('d-m-Y') . "<br />";
10         echo "<blockquote>" . $row->nieuws . "<br />";
11         echo "<br />";
12         echo "</blockquote></blockquote>";
13                                                                          
14        }
15     }
```

---

I tried many ways to find the sollutions but i couldn't find any, so i wonder how do i fix this issue when `$row->` is there for fetching the results.

Comment: `$date = new DateTime($row->datum);` and `echo $date->format('d-m-Y')` should work if `datum` is the date field in your database.... but make sure that your while loop is correctly braced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM famnews ORDER BY datum DESC")) {
    // display records if there are records to display
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $date = new DateTime($row->datum);
            echo "<blockquote><strong>Datum:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $date->format('d-m-Y') . "<br />";
            echo "<blockquote>" . $row->nieuws . "<br />";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "</blockquote></blockquote>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you.. So if i understand how it works, You ask first for result and between the brackets, you show the results like you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

you must pass date as argument of Date function:

```
$dateObj = new DateTime($row->dateintodb);
```

after you can set the format do you want:

```
echo $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
```

Hope I help you!
Bye 
Marco